# AWStats for multiple domains on same server using single install

Tags: awstats

I'm try to determine how to setting up AWStats for multiple sites on the server server. Ideally I would go to stats.mydomain.com and be able to see awstats for any site on my server. That is to say I don't want to have to set up stats.domain1.com, stats.domain2.com, ad nausea. Is it possible to create a single location and then switch between domains with via a form select. I feel I have seen this before, but have not found any web references.

I understand that I would need to still set up cron jobs, log files, etc to generate each domain individually. It's the centralized viewing that's important to me.

Any direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'd probably have to create the domain selection form yourself, but maybe it helps to know that `awstats.pl` recognizes `config=my.domain.name` as an argument, so you can use something like `http://stats.mydomain.com/awstats/awstats.pl?config=another.domain.com` to see stats of various domains on one site.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't kept up with AWStats for a couple of years, but still have some installs sticking around.

Generally, you can set up a fairly basic VirtualHost or ScriptAlias type thing in apache (pointing at the same awstats dir on disk), and then copy tweak some kind of awstats.sitetemplate.conf file, and then add a line to some script that gets called by cron to process stats.

There may be a better way these days ... the above is not exactly painful, but not exactly painless.

But AFAIK, that's the best you can do.

I'll be watching the thread to see if anyone else has a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is use webmin and awstats webmin module to create and manage multi domain in a ceterlize server (of couse need to use some kind of file transfer).

In case you cant install webmin you can create a simple web UI to manage multi domain log analyze (I've already deployed and use this)